# STANAG 3350B pcb guidelines

Tags: pcb, routing

What are the pcb routing standards that I have to follow for routing STANAG video signals on my pcb? Specifically, what are the impedance requirements? Is it better to route as a stripline or microstripline transmission line? Can I can use vias on my board?

Comment: STANAG 3350B is a standard for video signals and does not AFAIK address PCB layouts.

Comment: @MikeJ-UK - If the standard describes the electrical characteristics of the video signal, you should be able to derive the required PCB design specifications from it (principally controlled impedance, I would guess). However, this question significantly lacks enough information to be answerable at the moment.

Comment: @ConnorWolf, yes I actually wanted to know about the impedance and whether it is better to route as a stripline or microstripline transmission line( if i can use vias on my board)

Comment: Add the specifics of what you are trying to do to your question, and it will likely get reopened.

Comment: @ConnorWolf Actually we are creating a VPX backplane where I have to route the STANAG Video signal. The backplane is a 16 layer pcb and has the standard STANAG signals. It has standard RGB signals, Hsync Vsync signals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either stripline or microstrip will do at those frequencies. Just make sure your impedance matches. Ideally specify that the PCB house test it.

You can use vias.